# Copy big file from SD card to internal memory on android

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, file-permissions, android-sdcard

I'm new to Android and I want to copy a big file (approx. 2GB) **chosen by the user**(so I guess it should have permissions by default) to the internal memory. I already have the permissions added in AndroidManifest but I don't know how (and if I need to) use the Android [FileProivder](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider.html). I would also like to know how this process can happen on another thread such that the app is not blocked during the process and it can show the progress.

Comment: You dont need to use a file provider and the code for copying a small or a big file is the same.

Comment: Request permissions in manifest is not enough. You should add the code for runtime permissions. Well not allways... depending on the paths.

Comment: A code snippet would help :)

Comment: A code snippet of what?

Comment: First I'm opening a FilePicker, that gives me back a Uri, which is valid and all good. From now on how should I build the destination Uri to be able to copy the file using `DocumentsContract.copyDocument` (I don't know if there's another method for doing this)

Comment: FilePicker? ACTION_GET_CONTENT ? ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT?

Comment: ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT

Comment: The destination is a classic File path. So copying is (in a loop) reading bytes from an inputstream on the picked uri and then writing the bytes to a FileOutputStream. I never tried such a scenario with copyDocument().

Answer (score 1):

You could use a foreground service to do this and make sure the process doesn't get interrupted.

Build the service:

```java
public class CopyService extends Service {
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {

  }

  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // Run the moving code here
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
  }
}
```

It's important that you launch it as a foreground service (add permission in manifest), so it doesn't get destroyed after some time. You'll be required to add a notification then, which you can use for progress.

Read further on services: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services

As @blackapps pointed out it would be wise decision to check the permission and only start the service if it's granted. I usually check  if the permission is granted, if not I request it, if it is I follow. Then I check for it once again so I can see if the user granted it or not.

Google has a great article on how to request permissions:
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

How to move the file though? Here is the code I use in my own app:

```java
private static void moveFile(File from, File to) {
  InputStream inputStream;
  OutputStream outputStream;

  try {
    inputStream = new FileInputStream(from);
    outputStream = new FileOutputStream(to);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    while (inputStream.read(buffer) > 0) {
      outputStream.write(buffer);
    }

    inputStream.close();
    outputStream.close();

    // You may wish not to do this if you want to keep the original file
    from.delete();

    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "File copied successfully");

  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  // Stop service here
}
```

The code you'd like to run inside the service should be placed inside onStartCommand()

Comment: `so I can see if the user granted it or not. If no - I'd stop the service with stopSelf();` You should not start the service before you have permissions.

Comment: That's probably a better solution. Didn't think about that. Gonna update my answer